# Hibernate - variable name prefixed to column name

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-annotations

I have the following 2 classes

```
@Entity
Class AAA {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AAA_ID aaa_id;

    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    @ManyToOne
    private BBB bbb;
}

@Embeddable
class AAA_ID {
    @Column(name="id1")
    private String id1;

    @Column(name="id2")
    private String id2;
}

@Entity
Class BBB {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BBB_ID bbb_id;

    private String field3;
    private String field4;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bbb")
    @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "id1", referencedColumnName = "id1"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "id2", referencedColumnName = "id2")})
    private List<AAA> aaaList=new ArrayList<AAA>();

}

@Embeddable
class BBB_ID {
    @Column(name="id1")
    private String id1;

    @Column(name="id2")
    private String id2;

    @Column(name="id3")
    private String id3;

    @Column(name="id4")
    private String id4;
}
```

Then i coded it like this:

```
Root<AAA> AAARoot = criteriaQuery.from(AAA.class);
Join<AAA, BBB> customerContactPath = AAARoot.join("bbb");
criteriaQuery.select(AAARoot);
List<AAA> AAAList = getEntityManager().
                    createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

Its giving me the following exception

```
1869947 [8206263@qtp-21049255-16]
         ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - line 1,
               Table 'AAA' owned by 'ingres' does not contain column 'bbb_id1'.
```

As you can see the variable name `bbb` is being prefixed to the column `id1` which is why the above exception is coming.

P.S. I am new to hibernate.

Comment: Did you let hibernate create you table structure or did you do it yourself?

Comment: Its a legacy database. It wasnt created by hibernate

Comment: did you solve this problem?